# Stripe with Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, cordova, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe payments with my ionic app.

Following: 
https://github.com/tobyn/angular-stripe-checkout/blob/master/examples/simple.html

It seems to be looking good on the desktop browser. However,

```
<button stripe-checkout="doCheckout"
            data-key="key"
            data-name="My Name"
            data-currency="INR"
            data-email = "{{author}}@xxx.com"
            data-allow-remember-me = "false"
            data-description="Order #{{card.number}}"
            data-amount={{card.netAmount*100}}>
        Buy
    </button>
```

No matter what I write as the call back function - stripe-checkout - it is never called. I have tried `doCheckout` with the same being defined in my controller for the page's scope. Also tried `doCheckout()` instead. The call back is never executed.

Contorller Code:

```
.controller('TabHomeCardDetailCtrl',function($scope,$state....){
   ...
    $scope.doCheckout = function(token) {
        console.log("do Checkout is called")
        alert("Got Stripe token: " + token.id);
    };
```

Around Line 68 of `angular-stripe-checkout.js` it is checking if the callback is of type function - and the check always fails there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!

The definition of the function was at the wrong place.

I had created a custom directive - it should have been in the directive's controller. I was creating it in the main Controller and hoping it to work.